# Can anyone tell me how to create a durable publisher and subscriber for active mq topic message in c#?

Tags: c#, jms, activemq-classic

This is my existing code from subscriber but it is not working

```
_connection = factory.CreateConnection();

_connection.ClientId = "ID";

_connection.Start();

_session = _connection.CreateSession();

ITopic dest = _session.GetTopic(QUEUE_DESTINATION);

        using (IMessageConsumer consumer = _session.CreateDurableConsumer(dest,"myDurable",null,false))
        {
            IMessage message;

            while(true)
            {

            while ((message = consumer.Receive(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000))) != null)
            {

                var objectMessage = message as IObjectMessage;

                if (objectMessage != null)
                {
                    person = objectMessage.Body as Person;

                    if (person != null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(person.FirstName);

                        Console.WriteLine(person.LastName);
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Object Message is null");
                }
            }
        }
```

I am also not sure if anything needs to be done on the publisher side.
This code perfectly works when both publisher and subscriber are UP and RUNNING, 
But when the subscriber is DOWN and again UP and RUNNING the messages that are enqueued are not dequeued. I also verified this in active mq console. A durable consumer is created, but i don't receive the messages in the subscriber.

Comment: Does this help: http://remark.wordpress.com/articles/publish-subscribe-with-activemq-and-nms/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was i did not run the subscriber program first. It is necessary to run so that your subcriber first registers with activemq. You can find the durable consumer in your active mq console under the subcriber tab.